# Rotating List left and right

Tags: java, listiterator

I'm thinking about getting next and previous element from List, however I cannot handle this properly - problem occurs on the limits of List. Maybe someone has better concept to solve this issue?

```
public class Test {

    private char heading = 'N';
    List<Character> cardinal = Arrays.asList('N', 'E', 'S', 'W' );
    ListIterator<Character> iterator = cardinal.listIterator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println("heading = " + test.heading);

        test.rotateLeft(); System.out.println("Rotating left...");
        System.out.println("heading = " + test.heading);
        test.rotateLeft(); System.out.println("Rotating left...");
        System.out.println("heading = " + test.heading); 
   }

    public void rotateRight() {
        this.heading =
            (iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : cardinal.get(0));
    }  

    public void rotateLeft() {
        this.heading = 
                (iterator.hasPrevious() ? iterator.previous() : cardinal.get(3));
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`Collections.rotate(List, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int))?

Comment: Collections.rotate modifies the whole collection, it's not terribly efficient. But this is a small program, so I'm sure it'll fly...

Comment: Thanks Louis for your response! However this function changes composition of List, but I created my List as final - sorry for not mentioned about it. I'd rather want to retrive next or previous element from List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you reach the end of the list, you don't reset the iterator. From then on, `iterator.hasNext()` will always return false. An easy fix:

```
public void rotateRight() {
    if (!iterator.hasNext())
        iterator = cardinal.listIterator();
    this.heading = iterator.next();
}

public void rotateLeft() {
    if (!iterator.hasPrevious())
        iterator = cardinal.listIterator(cardinal.size());
    this.heading = iterator.previous();
}
```

If your list is `final`, it becomes even easier:

```
int index = 0;

public void rotateRight() {
    index = (index + 1) % cardinal.size();
    this.heading = cardinal.get(index);
}

public void rotateLeft() {
    index = (index - 1 + cardinal.size()) % cardinal.size();
    this.heading = cardinal.get(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your response! Looks great for me, but first rotation doesn't work - do you have any idea why?

Comment: It was off by one, just take away the `-1` from rotateLeft. Also, if your list is final, you don't even need to use an iterator. You can just use an index, and change that instead.

Comment: Andrew, your awesome! Really thank you for your help - I would waste much more my own time.